# Wrap a pack of forwarding references in a tuple

Tags: c++, tuples, c++14, perfect-forwarding, forwarding-reference

I have a function like this

```
template <typename... Args> void foo(Args&&... args);
```

to which I need to add an extra parameter at the end with a default argument. Since the pack needs to come last, I'm thinking of changing the function to

```
template <typename... Args> void foo(std::tuple<Args&&...> args,
                                     const std::string& name = {});
```

The question is, what is the best way to pass the arguments in a `tuple`.
My understanding is that in the `std::tuple<Args&&...>` the `Args` are not forwarding references anymore, but strictly rvalue references. How do I get the forwarding references behavior for `args` wrapped in a `tuple`, e.g. accept an `std::forward_as_tuple` and preserve the reference types of the individual tuple elements. Also, what's the best way to pass the tuple here,

```
std::tuple<Args&&...> args
```

or

```
const std::tuple<Args&&...>& args
```

or

```
std::tuple<Args&&...>&& args
```

?

And do I need to use `std::forward` on the tuple elements inside the function, or simply `std::get` them?

Comment: Alternatively, you can [extract](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5c682343371ab180) the last parameter

Comment: @Piotr, good idea. After some thought, I think not tying `args` into a tuple will work better in my code. Can you type your comment up as an answer? If no one answers the question about the tuple directly, I'll accept yours.

Comment: @Piotr, also great use of a dummy there. I was wondering how to handle empty pack cases, and that does it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *My understanding is that in the `std::tuple<Args&&...>` the `Args` are not forwarding references anymore*

Correct.

> *but strictly rvalue references*

Yes, unless `Args` are specified explicitly, in which case [reference collapsing](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Reference_collapsing) can turn them into lvalue references, i.e., `foo<int&>(...)` will result in `Args&& -> int& && -> int&`.

> *what is the best way to pass the arguments in a tuple.*

That depends on the intended usage of `foo`. If you don't need to know what `Args...` exactly are, you can probably get away with:

```
template <typename Tuple>
void foo(Tuple&& args, const std::string& name = {});
```

In such a case, individual types are still accessible using `std::tuple_element_t<N, std::decay_t<Tuple>>`.

If you *do* want to know `Args...` inside `foo` (without any additional levels of abstraction), you probably want to deduce the exact types, without any referenceness:

```
template <typename.... Args>
void foo(std::tuple<Args...>&& args, const std::string& name = {});
```

Note that if someone uses `std::forward_as_tuple` with lvalues and rvalues inside, the value categories will be stored in `Args` and you can still forward those arguments using `std::forward` (`std::forward` is *not* limited to forwarding references only, think of it as a conditional cast).

> *Also, what's the best way to pass the tuple here*

Probably `Tuple&&` as suggested earlier. If not, then again it depends on the usage. If you use `const std::tuple<Args...>&`, then by looking at the list of overloads for [`std::get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get), you'll see that the the value category and constness propagates to the return value of `std::get` (modulo [reference collapsing](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Reference_collapsing)). The same is with `std::tuple<Args...>&&`. Also, using the latter, you will have to use a tuple rvalue as an argument (`foo(std::forward_as_tuple(...), ...)` as opposed to `foo(my_tuple, ...)`).

An alternative solution would be to accept a parameter pack, and detect whether the last parameter is something that can be bound by `const std::string&` or not:

```
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

struct dummy {};

template <typename... Args>
void foo_impl(Args&&... args)
{
    const std::string& s = std::get<sizeof...(Args) - 1>(std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}

template <typename... Args>
auto foo(Args&&... args)
    -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible<std::string, std::tuple_element_t<sizeof...(Args), std::tuple<dummy, Args...>>>{}>
{
    foo_impl(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template <typename... Args>
auto foo(Args&&... args)
    -> std::enable_if_t<!std::is_constructible<std::string, std::tuple_element_t<sizeof...(Args), std::tuple<dummy, Args...>>>{}>
{
    foo_impl(std::forward<Args>(args)..., "default");
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5c682343371ab180)